# Datasets: Group and average

Tags: r, time-series, python, optimization

I have a huge dataset with hundreds of thousands of data of hourly climate data for each day.

```
observationTimeUtcIso;precip1Hour;precip24Hour;precip6Hour;pressureChange;relativeHumidity;snow1Hour;snow24Hour;snow6Hour;temperature;temperatureChange24Hour;temperatureDewPoint;temperatureFeelsLike;temperatureMax24Hour;temperatureMin24Hour;uvIndex;visibility;windSpeed;pointID
2018-02-14;0.44;15.71;2.05;1.5;97.8;0.0;0.0;0.0;6.5;1.5;6.2;3.4;7.0;3.6;0.0;3.9;16.3;8
2018-02-14;0.73;13.59;2.32;1.1;96.3;0.0;0.0;0.0;6.6;1.4;6.0;3.5;7.0;3.9;0.0;4.8;15.8;8
2018-02-14;0.24;11.29;2.16;1.1;97.5;0.0;0.0;0.0;6.5;1.3;6.2;3.7;7.0;4.1;0.0;4.8;14.2;8
2018-02-15;0.69;10.09;2.38;1.1;97.3;0.0;0.0;0.0;6.7;1.3;6.3;4.1;7.0;4.2;0.0;4.0;13.2;8
2018-02-15;0.54;10.49;2.43;0.9;96.5;0.0;0.0;0.0;6.8;1.2;6.3;4.2;7.0;4.3;0.0;6.0;13.4;8
2018-02-15;0.0;10.49;2.33;0.5;96.2;0.0;0.0;0.0;6.9;1.2;6.3;4.5;7.0;4.3;0.0;6.4;12.2;8
```

What I want to do, is to group by days and average for some variables, and sum for others, to get an output similar to:

```
Date;SumRain;AverageTemp
2018-02-14;1.41;6.5
2018-02-15;1.23;6.8
```

Is there an easy and optimal way to do this in python/R in a few of lines of codes? ive done it with bucles, but takes a lot of time for such huge datasets

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723208/aggregate-summarize-multiple-variables-per-group-e-g-sum-mean) on stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is a question for Stack Overflow, but (at least in R) it's quite simple with the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr) 
df <- df %>% mutate(date = as.Date(observationTimeUtcIso))
by_date <- df %>% group_by(date)

by_date %>% summarise(
  SumRain = sum(precip1Hour),   
  AverageTemp = mean(temperature))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
        date SumRain AverageTemp
      <date>   <dbl>       <dbl>
1 2018-02-14    1.41    6.533333
2 2018-02-15    1.23    6.800000
```